# Add rotation to OpenTK transformation matrix?

Tags: c#, opengl, matrix, opentk

How do I *add* rotation to my transformation matrix? You may think `Matrix4.CreateTranslation(ref translation, out matrix)` will do the job, but it just resets the matrix and applies its rotation.

I found two solutions: `Gl.Rotate()`, which doesn't even exist, and `Matrix4.Rotate()`, which is deprecated.

So how do I add the rotation to my already manipulated matrix, without resetting it?

Comment: So do it "manually" (using matrix multiplication)?

Comment: @UnholySheep you mean creating three more matrices and multipling them? That would have been my salution, but I want the most profound salution, the right one, the normal one

Comment: Why do you need 3 more matrices to "add" rotation to a translation?

Comment: How do you suggest me to do it?

Comment: `rotationMatrix * translationMatrix` - that's how you compose a transformation matrix.

Comment: `Matrix4 transl;
            Matrix4.CreateTranslation(ref translation,  out transl);
            Matrix4 rotX; 
            Matrix4.CreateRotationX(degreeToRadian(rx), out rotX);
            ...
            Matrix4 transf = transl * rotX * rotY * rotZ;`   
Like this?

Comment: Have you tried `Matrix4.CreateFromAxisAngle()`? If you tried  `Matrix4.Rotate()` , Visual Studio would tell you to use this.

Comment: That's a good solution, thank you